# TextBox not getting focus

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating the DataGridTemplateColumn dynamically.

```
  var binding = new Binding
                    {

                        Path = new PropertyPath("MyProperty"),
                        UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus

                    };

                    var converterParameter = new List<object> { header, rows, myGrid };
                    binding.Converter = new MyConverter();
                    binding.ConverterParameter = converterParameter;


                    var textBoxValue = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
                    totalUnitsValue.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
                    totalUnitsValue.SetValue(TextBox.HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Right);
                    totalUnitsValue.SetValue(TextBox.WidthProperty, 40.0);
                    totalUnitsValue.SetValue(TextBox.MarginProperty, new Thickness(4, 0, 10, 0));

var factoryElement = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
                    factoryElement.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);
                    factoryElement.AppendChild(textBoxValue );

  var column = new DataGridTemplateColumn
            {
                Header = header,
                CellTemplate = new DataTemplate { VisualTree = factoryElement }
            };

            myGrid.Columns.Add(column);
```

**This works fine for few columns. But if i create 10 or more columns (80 -90) textBoxes then the last created TextBoxes do not allow me to change the value or do not allow me to put focus on the TextBox. It becomes like TextBlock.**

**EDIT:**

IF I REMOVE THE STACKPANEL, THEN THERE IS NO ISSUE WITH THE TEXTBOX BUT I NEED TO SHOW MORE THAN ONE ELEMENT, SO I NEED TO HAVE SOME SORT OF CONTAINER.ANY HELP ON THAT.

Please guide what could be tghe

Comment: It may be some issue with the UI. Example: if the DataGrid expands too much, other element background may cover some part of it. Without your UI code it is difficult to say...

Comment: Have you tried the prefered way for creating elements in code? By writing a piece of xaml and load it via the XamlReader? See the [remarks to this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory.aspx).

Comment: This seems like an virtualization issue. Try setting VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="false"